# How to model a m2m relation where the related table can be a city, a region (state) or a country

Tags: python, django

In Django I have theses models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    born_place = models.ForeignKey(???)
    dead_place = models.ForeignKey(???)
    live_places = models.ManyToManyField(???)
    work_places = models.ManyToManyField(???)

class Country(models.Model):
    iso = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Region(models.Model):
    iso = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    region = models.ForeignKey('Region')
```

All the *places* (`born_place`, `dead_place`, `live_places`, `work_places`) can be a `City` or a `Region` or a `Country`. And a `City` should necessarily have a `Region`, and a `Region` should necessarily have a `Country`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance. Thanks for all the answers. They are all good answers. Finally I choose the model inheritance solution. I choose it because it suits my needs and structure pretty well (one coherent table for each type (country, etc.)). The only difference with the models proposed by *o.elias* is that I didn't put any fields in the Territory class. This way Country, Region and City tables are more *coherent* (all the info are at the same place). I need that because some tables can be consult/edit directly (with MS Access, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use model inheritance

```
class Territory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Country(Territory):
    iso = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)

class Region(Territory):
    iso = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')

class City(Territory):
    region = models.ForeignKey('Region')

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    born_place = models.ForeignKey(Territory)
    dead_place = models.ForeignKey(Territory)
    live_places = models.ManyToManyField(Territory)
    work_places = models.ManyToManyField(Territory)
```

Best regards!

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach. I need to play a bit with this one to see all the implications (admin, table structure, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

> All the places (born_place, dead_place, live_places, work_places) can be a City or a Region or a Country.

What you need in this case is a [generic foreign key](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). In Django this can be achieved through the handy [contenttypes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework.

From the documentation:

> There are three parts to setting up a GenericForeignKey:
>
> 1. Give your model a ForeignKey to ContentType.
> 2. Give your model a field that can store a primary-key value from the models you'll be relating to. (For most models, this means an IntegerField or PositiveIntegerField.) This field must be of the same type as the primary key of the models that will be involved in the generic relation. For example, if you use IntegerField, you won't be able to form a generic relation with a model that uses a CharField as a primary key.
> 3. Give your model a GenericForeignKey, and pass it the names of the two fields described above. If these fields are named "content_type" and "object_id", you can omit this -- those are the default field names GenericForeignKey will look for.

Comment: Also an interesting solution. I need to play with it. But my feeling is that generic foreignkey is more suited to work the other way around (like in the tag example, you add Tags to many models). In my case, if I understand correctly, I will add Artists to Country or Region or City. I think it will work but it look less elegant to me. But I can be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

well.. yea maybe you could use generic relations. But i think that you could solve you some problems by thinking outside the box.

i'd say that you could create a Territory model instead of Country,Region and City; and then use a [recursive relationship](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships)

```
class Territory(models.Model):
   iso = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

this will create a hierarchy structure for your territory, so now you could use as many divisions as you like (for exemple, Continents, Planets,Community) and you wont have to change your models. As for the Artist, you could do something like:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    born_place = models.ForeignKey(Territory)
    dead_place = models.ForeignKey(Territory)
    live_places = models.ManyToManyField(Territory)
    work_places = models.ManyToManyField(Territory)
```

so now... the born_place can be a City, a Region, a Planet... anything you want! i guess that was your question. I'm no expert in django, this is just a generic way to solve this kind of problems in O.O.P.

Comment: After I post my question, I thought of this solution. The only difference in my version is that I have a "kind" field (choices field with possible value: country, region, city) in the Territory class. This way I can filter only the cities or the countries, etc. And more important, I can put constraint that the city's parent should be a region and the region's parent should be a country.

For the moment, that's my favorite solution. But I need to evaluate more the 2 other solutions, generic relations and model inheritance.

Comment: oh yeah! i forgot about the "kind" field, i usually call it "type"..
the disavantage of using inheritance is that you'll have to modify your code if you want to introduce new "types" or "kinds" that's why inheritance is a good solution when you have a certain number of elements that wont change over the time.. witch might be your case... I often use this solution when working on "categories" and "subcategories" that are more dynamically created

Comment: About "kind" I use it in general in python (not especially in Django) instead of "type" to avoid problem because "type" is a keyword in python. But I agree that "type" is a better definition. And merci for pointing me the differences between inheritance and your solution. Do you have any opinions on the generic relations approach?

Comment: i dont like them! in my opinion,if you use generic relations you could loose integrity of your data, and maybe creating relations that dont make any sense, when you could solve the problem in a good-christian-old-fashioned way using O.O.P

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django's Generic Relations [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) and [here](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/), which will let you key to various types of object, rather than only a specific one.